# How does a hobby charger work?

Tags: battery-charging

As far as I understand, a hobby charger - for example to charge a pack containing 4 batteries in series - is wired as so:

[image]

That is, with a heavy gauge "power" connector wired across the battery pack, and a 5 conductor "balance" connector wired across each of the batteries in the pack.

It seems to me that the 5 balance conductors are all that would be needed to properly measure and charge each of the constituent batteries (and also measure the total voltage across the pack).

Why does the charger also have the heavy gauge connection across the whole pack?

Comment: A pack like this would only have 3 balance connections, not 5.

Answer (score 5):

It's because charging circuitry is complex and expensive, but dissipative balancing circuitry is simple and cheap.

Therefore, it is cheaper to have one big charger common to all cells and multiple individual balance circuits than it is to have many individual chargers (which would also need to be isolated and floating relative to each other).

How much cheaper? By about 1/n cells. If you're charging a 4-cell, 16V battery at 20A you can either use a one 16V, 20A circuit or you can use four 4V, 20A circuits. Those 4V circuits still needs to support 20A so each one isn't going to be noticeably smaller or less expensive than the 16V, 20A circuit. So your approach would be about four times bigger, four times as complex, and cost about four times more.

And then you would have your balance charger which now only has 5 conductors...except each conductor would be heavy gauge wire since each one must support all the charge current which also makes for a very unwieldly battery.

Comment: I see. It wasn't apparent to me that it was entirely safe to charge all of the cells together, in series. I now (believe I) understand that it is quite safe if the cells are all brought to identical voltages before beginning to charge. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @tschmit The cells don't have to be equal voltage when charging independently because they are being charged independently.

Comment: @tschmit cells must however be brought to identical voltages before connecting them in _parallel_, which is what you might have read somewhere

Answer (score 3):

> It seems to me that the 5 **balance conductors are all that would be**
> **needed** to properly measure and charge each of the constituent
> batteries (and also measure the total voltage across the pack).

Only on a small battery with low charging current. Some 'hobby' chargers *do* charge through the balance connector, but they are typically limited to 1~2 A maximum.

The [FMA Cellpro Multi4](http://w.swm1.com/flying/FMA/Multi4/Multi4_review.html) did up to 4A, but the [JST XH](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/resources/datasheets/jst/xh-connector) balance connectors used on most 'hobby' batteries are only rated for 3 A (When new. After a few hundred insertions however...). Furthermore, although this charger does charge through the balance connector it still only applies voltage to the whole pack and then passive balances the cells.

Chargers that do each cell independently have the problem of keeping the individual charge circuits isolated from each other, which unnecessarily duplicates circuitry and requires some method to pass settings and voltage measurements etc. across the gap. Therefore this technique is generally used only in dedicated chargers with 2-3 cells and fixed (non-programmable) charging current and voltage. These typically use a [switch mode power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply) (SMPS) with multiple isolated outputs, each feeding a single cell linear charging IC like the [TP4056](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf).

'Hobby' chargers are designed to charge a wide range of battery chemistries and sizes safely and accurately at reasonable cost. Some types like NiMH and Lead acid do not have balance connectors, so the charger must be able to charge a battery through its 'power' connectors anyway. If a Li-ion/Lipo battery is in good health it doesn't need much if any balancing, so the user may opt to not connect the balance lead for convenience.

The single charging circuit can easily be electronically programmed to control overall charging current and voltage, with the balance connector used to monitor individual cells voltages and balance the cells if required. The balance connector has low current going through it so contact resistance isn't an issue, and a large battery can be charged at much higher current through the 'power' connectors. This technique provides a more flexible, more reliable and more affordable charging system for 'hobby' use.

Comment: Also thank you very much, Bruce, for your insightful and detailed reply. Apart from adding to DKNguyen's thoughts, your observation that they are designed to handle different types of batteries helped me understand the design decision. I also found it very interesting - if I understood correctly - that the charger is also monitoring individual cells during the charge cycle, and may interrupt the charging to rebalance cells before continuing. Given the cost and flexibility constraints, it seems like a rather brilliant design.